# How to convert string to binary

Tags: dart

Hey is there a dart build in way of converting a string to eg a binarystring
print("a".toBinary()) => 0110 0001

or what do you think would be the best way to do so?

Comment: For what purpose? Client side or server side?

Comment: Would be nice if it works for both sides

Comment: If the answers do what you want this shouldn't be a problem. I wasn't sure you meant with 'to **eg** a binarystring'.

Comment: ah k ;) yeah the answers are perfect. was just a reflex to answer ^^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the Dart equivalents of javascript's `String.charCodeAt` method.  In Dart there are two options depending on whether you want to the character codes for the whole string or just a single character within the string.

- https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-core.String#id_codeUnitAt
- https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-core.String#id_codeUnits

`String.codeUnitAt` is a method that returns an int for the character at a given index in the string. You use it as follows:

```dart
String str = 'hello';
print(str.codeUnitAt(3)); //108
```

You can use `String.codeUnits` to convert the entire string into their integer values:

```dart
String str = 'hello';
print(str.codeUnits); //[104, 101, 108, 108, 111]
```

If you need to then convert those integers into their corresponding binary strings you'll want to us `int.toRadixString` with an argument of 2

```dart
String str = 'hello';
List<String> binarys = str.codeUnits.map((int strInt) => strInt.toRadixString(2));
print(binarys); //(1101000, 1100101, 1101100, 1101100, 1101111)
```

Comment: my problem was more going from codeunits to binary (toRadixString).. thx

Answer (score 12):

You need to say which format you need. Strings are sequences of 16-bit integers. In some settings they are interpreted as UTF-16, where some integers (code units) represent a single code point, other code points require two code units. In yet other settings, a "character" is more than one code point. So, to convert a string to bits, you need to be exact about how you interpret the string.

Here you write only eight bits for an "a", not, e.g., "000000000110001", so I assume you only consider ASCII strings.

Let's assume it's all ASCII, and you want eight-bit results:

```
var binstring = string.codeUnits.map((x) => x.toRadixString(2).padLeft(8, '0'))
                                .join();
```

Comment: In UTF-16, some codepoints need one 16-bit code unit, some need two.

Comment: Ack, yes. What I wrote sounded like they all needed two code units, not just some of them. I'll rephrase that.

Comment: thank you yeah was only considering ascii.
I like both answers, even though I like the oneliner, im giving the tick to the other one due to stepbystep description :) still thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import 'dart:core';

void main() {
    String name = "hello";
    for(int binary in name.codeUnits)print(binary.toRadixString(2));
}
```